# Store two bits in double

Tags: pointers, double, 64-bit, bit

I need to store two bits (tags) in a double number. I am willing to throw away some extra precision from those numbers of course. I know that I will need to fill those two extra bits with 0 or 1 before doing actual arithmetics on them. Basically I need something like "tagged pointer/double", so I can store a pointer and a double in the same  64 bit location on x64 platform, and choose between them based on the tag. One bit could have been enough, but I need to store there something else sometimes.

I know that for pointers it is very simple, just align them so that least significant bits are always zero, store data there and clear before dereferencing. Or you can use top 16 bits, but clear them all to 0 (or all to 1) before dereferencing. Storing extra data in `uint64` is also very simple, just use most significant bit, clear before use. You loose half of the ints range of course. But for doubles... They are stored in three parts, sign, exponent and fraction (see picture, courtesy of Wikipedia). Which are the two less important (precision-wise) bits in the double, that you can throw away to store your tags in them? Least significant parts of the exponent? Higher bits of fraction? I am willing to do clearing/shifting before using the number.

[image]

Comment: You can't really throw away stuff, take a look at the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Examples), bits mean different things depending on what number is represented, will using 32bit floating point suffice? You can store a 32bit number in 64 bits.

Comment: You could still use the bottom two bits in principle. But it's up to you whether precision or range matters more. The high bits of the fraction are the *most* important